# Any way to see HashCode of primitive types?

Tags: java, hashcode

Mugging up basic D.S....I read that, no `hashCode()` method for primitive type `int` is available and if called on `int`, it will throw error

> error: int cannot be dereferenced

Does this means that if `int n = 10` then its `HashCode` will also be 10??

If i still need to see hascode for `int` in below program, is there a method to see it, like `Integer` `Wrapper`???

```
public static void main(String []args){
       String me = "hello";
       int n = 10;

       int h1 = me.hashCode();
       int h2 = n.hashCode();

       System.out.println(h1);
       System.out.println(h2);
     }
```

Comment: You get the error "int cannot be dereferenced" because *int cannot be dereferenced* :)

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun : haha..yeah..i guess that sums up the answer for me....thankx mate!! :)

Comment: Can I ask why you want to know this? Note that there is no standard the requires a `hashCode()` to be a certain value even for non-primitive types. An implementation can probably return constant value, say `0` for `hashCode()` for *all* objects and still be compliant.

Comment: @MiserableVariable : m just learning this and read the `hashcode()` method in the libraries, out of curiosity, wanted to see the output, so that,i may implement some basic `hashcode` method on my own.....do i make sense to u?? :)

Comment: I am afraid not. The only real use of hashCode is as hashing function.

Comment: @MiserableVariable : but to understand anything, you should know the basics of its building element too...right??? I m just trying to get my base here....`real use` i understand, but ( *just for example* ) before compiling a program its always good to know little bit about compilers too..m working on this logic....now do i make sense?? :D

Comment: It makes perfect sense. You should try to find out how hashing functions work and how they provide constant time lookups. From there, you can go on good and bad hashing functions. Wikipedia has some good articles. Java's implementations are I believe very good but it is more important to understand how hashing works then to understand how hashCode is implemented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot invoke methods on primitive types.

`n` is declared as `int`. It does not have methods.

It does not make sense to think like

> If i still need to see hascode for int in below program

You could create an `Integer` object and get its `hashCode()`

```
Integer.valueOf(n).hashCode()
```

`Integer#hashCode()` is implemented as

```
public int hashCode() {
    return value;
}
```

where `value` is the `int` value it's wrapping.

> Does this means that if int n = 10 then its HashCode will also be 10??

The `int` doesn't have a hashcode. Its `Integer` wrapper will however have the value of the `int` it's wrapping.

Answer (score 4):

## New Convenience Methods (Java 8)

Java 8 brought static methods to more conveniently generate a hash code for primitive values. These methods are stored on the primitive equivalent class.

Mentioned in [this discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/1y9e6t/ama_were_the_google_team_behind_guava_dagger/cfijudl) with bondolo (Mike Duigou?), one of the OpenJDK developers, talking about how [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) has influenced the core libraries in Java.

> In Java 8 examples of small Guava inspired JDK additions include static hashCode methods added to the primitive types.

- [`Boolean.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#hashCode-boolean-)
- [`Integer.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode-int-)
- [`Float.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#hashCode-float-)

…and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Only Objects have methods. Not primitives. You might want

```
 int h2 = new Integer(n).hashCode();
```

Just create an Wrapper of `int` and invoke method on it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is `int` is not a `Java` object and there is not such thing call `hashCode()` for `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is not an `Object`. It doesn't have methods.

If you want some idea of how the `Integer` class works, you can Grep Oracle's Java code:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.hashCode%28%29

In particular, this confirms that the return of `hashCode()` for an `Integer` object is indeed its underlying integer value.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is not an object in Java. It is a primitive data type. However, you can use `Integer` class to get the hashcode of an int.

```
System.out.println(new Integer(n).hashCode());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense for primitives to have hash codes. They themselves are the best hash codes you can ask for.

Integer hash code is implemented to redundantly return the value itself, so that when used in a java.util.HashSet for example, it maps to itself.

```
public int hashCode() {
    return value;
}
```